# Django сортировка по рейтингу

Tags: python, django

Создаю программу, в которой есть список студентов, в ней нужно сделать сортировку по рейтингу студентов. На данный момент это выглядит так, не могу разобраться в чём проблема, ошибок никаких не выдаёт.

````py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follows = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self", related_name="followed_by", symmetrical=False, blank=True
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="non")
    nap = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="non")
    curse = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="1")
    raiting = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="1000")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


def profile_list(request):
    profiles = Profile.objects.exclude(user=request.user)
    query = request.GET.get('search','')

    if query:
       profiles = Profile.objects.filter (Q(name__iregex=query) | Q(nap__iregex=query) | Q(curse__iregex=query))
    else: profiles = Profile.objects.all

    sort = request.GET.get('sort')
    if sort:
            profiles = Profile.objects.all.order_by("raiting")
    return render(request, "dwitter/profile_list.html", {"profiles": profiles})```
````

Comment: Какая проблема-то? Что конкретно вы делаете, что конкретно вы ожидаете, что конкретно происходит вместо ожидаемого?

Comment: Могу предположить, что проблема в методе all. Вы его используете без скобок.

Comment: Попробуйте Profile.objects.all()

Либо посмотрите что вы даете в get запросе, возможно там checkbox, который имеет нестандартное поведение.

sort = request.GET.get('sort', False)
sort = True if sort == '' else False

Comment: Добавил скобки в метод all, не помогло. Get запрос как я понял отправляется, так как при нажатие функция работает, но не полностью. Проблема в том, что не работает именно .order_by("raiting").

Comment: Если этот order_by находится под условием if, то отсюда логичный вопрос — а это самое условие if вообще истинно? Вы проверяли значение sort?